# HTML page with horizontal tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I create horizontal tabs like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewXO4.png ?

Code:

```
<label class="formlabel">Title 1:</label>
<div id="radio_form">
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="status">Activated</label>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="status">Deactivated</label>
    <br><br>
</div>
<label class="formlabel">Title 2:</label>
<input name="input2" type="text" class="forminput" />
<label class="formlabel">Title 3:</label>
<input name="input3" type="text" class="forminput" />  

<input class="formsubmit" type="submit" name ='submit' value="Save">
```

I would like to have title/input 3 on  tab 2 for example, could i do this with CSS using divs and styling?

If someone have a solution that include jQuery or JavaScript please share it.

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is explained at https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/), simple to use and you can use prebuild style or change with yous CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say give this a try [MetroUI](https://metroui.org.ua/tabcontrol.html)

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/6ugs25td/)

```
<div class="tabcontrol" data-role="tabControl" data-open-target="#frame_3_2">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#frame_3_1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="#frame_3_2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="#frame_3_3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="frames bg-grayLight">
        <div class="frame" id="frame_3_1" style="display: block;">1</div>
        <div class="frame" id="frame_3_2" style="display: none;">2</div>
        <div class="frame" id="frame_3_3" style="display: none;">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/ew072daa/)

**HTML**

```
<!--custom tab-->
<div class="tab"> <a target="1" class="active">HOME</a>
 <a target="2">PERSONAL</a>
 <a target="3">EDUCATIONAL</a>

</div>
<div class="details" id="link1">Home details goes here</div>
<div class="details" id="link2" style="display:none;">Personal details goes here</div>
<div class="details" id="link3" style="display:none;">Educational details goes here</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".tab a").click(function () {
        $(".tab a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".details").hide();
        var target = $(this).attr('target');
        $("#link" + target).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution

```js
    $('#tabs li a').click(function() {
       $('#tabs li a').removeClass("selected_tab");
       $(this).addClass("selected_tab"); 
    });
```

```css
#tabs {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
}

#tabs li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom:0;
}

#tabs li a {
    display:block;
    padding:0.3em;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.selected_tab {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

#tab_content {
    width:100%;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a class="selected_tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab_content">asdsda</div>
```